# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getIMEI() from the type Util

Tags: android, exception, imei

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String test =  Util.imei();
}


import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class Util{
    Context context;

    public Util(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String imei() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }
}
```

Getting error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method imei() from the type Util".
If I change the line to:

```
public static String imei() {
    ...
    static Context context;
```

I get an error and crash app.("E/AndroidRuntime(629): Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two ways to write it:

**1st** *non static*

```
public class Util {
    Context context;

    public Util(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String imei() {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }
}
```

and then in `onCreate` method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Util u = new Util(this);
    String test =  u.imei();
}
```

**2nd** *static*

```
public class Util {
    public static String imei(Context context) {
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
    }
}
```

and then in `onCreate` method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String test =  Util.imei(this);
}
```

Comment: i assume that you create the `AsyncTask` in an `Activity`. Then write `String test = Util.imei(TheActivity.this);` or else you have to construct `AsyncTask` passing the `context`

Answer (score 0):

Create a reference of the Util class first before accessing its methods.

```
Util util = new Util();
String _imei = util.imei();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a method inside a class without creating an object for it. Only for static method we can call like that. In your case, create an object for `Util` and call `imei()` using that object.

Like,

```
Util utilObj = new Util();
String imei = utilObj.imei();
```

Hope this helps.